# How to resolve ValueError on dataclasses?

Tags: python-dataclasses

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\train.py", line 54, in 
from object_detection.legacy import trainer
File "C:\tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\legacy\trainer.py", line 27, in 
from object_detection.builders import optimizer_builder
File "C:\tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\builders\optimizer_builder.py", line 25, in 
from official.modeling.optimization import ema_optimizer
File "C:\tensorflow\models\official\modeling\optimization_*init*_.py", line 19, in 
from official.modeling.optimization.configs.optimization_config import *
File "C:\tensorflow\models\official\modeling\optimization\configs\optimization_config.py", line 31, in 
@dataclasses.dataclass
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\x0133252\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\Lib\dataclasses.py", line 1223, in dataclass
return wrap(cls)
^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\x0133252\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\Lib\dataclasses.py", line 1213, in wrap
return _process_class(cls, init, repr, eq, order, unsafe_hash,
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\x0133252\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\Lib\dataclasses.py", line 958, in _process_class
cls_fields.append(_get_field(cls, name, type, kw_only))
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\x0133252\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\Lib\dataclasses.py", line 815, in _get_field
raise ValueError(f'mutable default {type(f.default)} for field '
ValueError: mutable default <class 'official.modeling.optimization.configs.optimizer_config.SGDConfig'> for field sgd is not allowed: use default_factory

Getting error while training

Comment: Sorry - read a little bit on how to post questions, maybe navigate other qeustions around - there is no way that is close to being answerable here.